# Site collection can not be moved

Tags: sharepoint-online

In preparation for  the upgrade to Sharepoint 2013 I need to move all my sharepoint 2010 standard edition  site collections “32” which they are in separate Databases  content (SQL 2012)  in one database content so I can run mount powers shell command to web application ,  I get the error :

> Move-SPSite : Site collection http://contoso.com database “db_my”.
>   Site collection will not be moved At line:1 char:12
>   + Move-SPSite <<<<  -Identity http://contoso.com  -DestinationDatabase My_db     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData:
>   (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveSite:SPCmdletMoveSite) [Move-SPSite],
>   SPCmdle    tException     + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveSite

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you have an update regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you move all site in one content database and try to upgrade that it will be a slow upgrade and if you hit any error it will be very difficult to troubleshoot.

Best Approach would migrate Content database as it is.

If you still would like to proceed with moving the site to single content DB then you can try below steps instead move because it might be getting timed out

1. perform a site collection backup using the Backup-SPSite cmdlet
2. delete the site collection from the content database that is actually hosting it
3. pre-create the new SharePoint content database that will host the site collection using the New-SPContentDatabase cmdlet
4. use the Restore-SPSite cmdlet to restore the site collection to the newly created content database.

You can also check the ULS logs for errors which will help for further troubleshooting.